# NodeJS and MongoDB - Array of ObjectId how to return Objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have in a collection an reference array of ObjectId. And I want to return the object's data linked with those Ids in the json response.

```
retrieveFromUser: function( req, res ) {
    var user_id =   req.params.user_id;
    User.findById( user_id, function( err, user ) {
        if( err ) {
            res.send( 404, "Unable to find user");
        } else {
            // This returns the array but I want the objects data
            return res.json( user.constructions );
        }
    });
}
```

How can I do that ?
thanks a lot !

Comment: If you do <code>console.log(user.constructions)</code> what is the result?

Comment: It's the array of ids: ["52556b4081b9cae812000002", etc...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method

```
retrieveFromUser: function( req, res ) {
 var user_id =   req.params.user_id;
    User.findOne({ _id: user_id }).populate('constructions').exec(function( err, user ) {
        if( err ) {
            res.send( 404, "Unable to find user");
        } else {
            // This returns the array but I want the objects data
            return res.json( user.constructions );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting  a TypeError: Cannot call method 'populate' of undefined...

Comment: @MaT, are you using mongoose? Which version of mongoose you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am using Mongoose 3.6.20. And if I use findOne, I have the undefined error.

Comment: All mongoose find methods returns Query objects http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query (ref https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L880, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and findById it is just wrapper around findOne. All Query objects have populate methods, try to check it by yourself by `console.log(User.findOne({ _id: user_id }))`

Comment: I solved my error, this was due to a wrapped function. Thanks a lot !